# Can't convert 0.3 to IEEE754

Tags: binary, floating-point, numbers, point, ieee

I am trying to convert 0.3 to IEEE754 format.
What I am getting is: `0011111010011001100110011001 1001`, but
what I should get is: `0011111010011001100110011001 1010`. As you can see, the last 4 digits differ. I multiplied 0.3 with 2 until I found the period and then, after filling the mantisa with 001, I filled the rest of the mantisa with the period (1001). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to round, not truncate. At bit 25 the pattern continues: 10011001...
Since bit 25 and beyond is > 1/2 ULP, you have to round up. That will give you the answer you are expecting.